# What could disable most of a space ship in space?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, spaceships

Is there anything in space that could disable most of a large (like with hundreds of passengers) spaceship without destroying the actual ship? I'm thinking something like an EM pulse, or some other kind of unexpected accident on board. Kind of like disabling destroying the main engines (but not, say, minor manoeuvring thrusters) & most but not all of the electronics.

The problem is, the project to launch has gone through decades of planning, testing, research & development, etc. so it has to be something completely unexpected (rather than just poor workmanship or something) or at least very unlikely and so difficult to prevent that they considered it an acceptable risk.

What could cause this? If an EMP, what would be the source?

Comment: I'm not at all sure this can be reasonably answered in its current form. It might be answerable if you tell us more about the spaceship, though.

Comment: "This mission is too important for me to allow you to jeopardize it." - [HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film))

Answer (score 3):

- Internal fire and explosion. Something goes wrong with a fuel and oxidizer pump for one of the maneuvering thrusters.
- Software bug. The navigation computers simply crash whenever somebody tries to reboot them. Unfortunately all of them run the same version of the same operating system.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional solution is **sabotage**. Sure there are lots of accidents that can disable only parts of ship and it is possible that there will be no collateral damage to life support, but sabotage is only one where such selective damage is likely and expected.

The reasons for sabotage obviously depend on the story.

Answer (score 2):

**A Meteoroid Impact**

Pace ships are likely to be hardened against any sort of phenomena that they're likely to encounter. Solar flares and other electromagnetic disturbances would be damaging for an unshielded spacecraft, but for a large vessel, they're common enough that precautions are likely to be taken.

Moderately large meteoroidss, on the other hand, are both rare to encounter in space and very difficult to shield against. Most shielding systems on a spacecraft, such as [Whipple shields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipple_shield), are optimized to protect against significantly more common micrometeoroid impacts, but a moderately larger meteoroid or comet would have far to much energy to be absorbed by this type of shield, especially if collided with head on.

If such a meteoroid were to impact the engines on your spacecraft, it could easily disable them, and with proper engineering and luck leave the main passenger compartment of the vehicle relatively unharmed. If your spacecraft uses a common power source for both propulsion and auxiliary electronics, the destruction of that power source would cripple the ship in the manner you're looking for. Hopefully, there exists some form of backup power generation which can at least run life support on the ship, or your travelers will all asphyxiate, freeze, or burn up in short order.

Answer (score 2):

@o.m.'s answer is great, I also wanted to add incidental damage that may occur due to navigational errors. Think steering too close to a star, too a gravitational field, a particularly dense nebula, etc. These may stress systems beyond their specification and could cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: @fi12 Thanks :) Nice place you got here!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I get to destroy a spaceship!

Here are a few ways to do that...

- you said they've spent decades working on this. Perhaps some part or parts of the ship are made of outdated technology that the government didn't want to replace. This machinery broke down and caused the rest of the ship to be mainly incapacitated.
- Solar Flare
- Meteor (depends on the size of your ship)
- Human Error, Apollo 13 was also a government project that had been planned and worked on for years by America best scientists.
- Sabotage